# Adding a Fuelux wizard to an Angular project

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, fuelux

I'm reading https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux in order to get familiar with the Fuelux wizard, and how I can integrate it with my AngularJS project.

In the non-AMD section it says :

**Non-AMD
If you'd prefer not to use AMD, simply add the loader script to the head tag of your page:**

```
<script src="http://www.fuelcdn.com/fuelux/2.6.1/loader.min.js" type="text/javascript">    </script>
```

but something in jquery is conflicting with my angular routes.

I'm also using this as a guide, and adding the necessary css links and requirejs links; however the wizard does not render properly (as if it were missing the css styling).

[wizard](http://jsbin.com/kesikoli/1/edit)

UPDATE:
In my latest attempt, after downloading from https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/tree/3.0.0-wip , I'm still getting the non-formatted wizard. Please see screen shot :

[image: Wizard unformatted]

Answer (score 1):

FuelUX 2.x is AMD only. The loader.js is a polyfill of sorts (almond.js- a minimal AMD API implementation) that allows AMD, just so you don't have to load require.js yourself, but it's still there.

The latest version [FuelUX 3](https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/tree/3.0.0-wip) is a WIP branch and is UMD (Universal Module Definition) which means it can be used with/without AMD via  tags with only Bootstrap and JQuery as dependencies. You might try it.

Comment: interesting but I don't see any non-AMD examples in that download. I'm experimenting now with the minimal files loaded up in my index.html (i.e. css and js files).

Comment: I've added a screen shot to show how the wizard is not styling properly.

Comment: This doc preview version is a few weeks old, but it might help. http://fuelux-docs.herokuapp.com/javascript.html#wizard Also review http://fuelux-docs.herokuapp.com/getting-started.html#template

Comment: You'll want to get your markup and CSS/header from https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/blob/3.0.0-wip/index.html and your JS/header from https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/blob/3.0.0-wip/test/fuelux-browser-globals.html from index.html

Comment: I found some straight-forward html/css code to implement my 6-step wizard. I changed up the buttons using Bootstrap CSS styling, as well as an AngularJS directive to manipulate the wizard steps. If interested in code, please comment.

Comment: @user969068 - no sorry, i can't. this post is so old, and was for a prototype - the code for which I don't have.